# can't find visual studio menu command: File > New > "Import > import from xcode"

Tags: xcode, visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2019 Pro (latest version) does not show the "Import from xcode" command that I need for Xamarin.IOS development.

This [Microsoft doc Import an Xcode project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/import-an-xcode-project?view=vs-2019) reads...

> On the File menu, choose New, Import, Import from Xcode. This command
>   starts the Import from Xcode wizard dialog.

...but my File > New menu does not have "Import".  It only has: Project, File, Project from existing code.

WHAT I'VE TRIED...
I paired VS with the Mac but still no "Import" menu.
I am able to build Xamarin.IOS apps and run them on my iPad connected to the Mac.

Comment: do you have the "Mobile development with C++" workload installed?

Comment: The tutorial you are using is NOT for Xamarin. It's in a different section which shows one of the many solutions you can use for mobile development using Visual Studio

Comment: Jason, it is check-marked in Visual Installer, so I assume it's installed.